# AM/PM showing as A3/P3 when trying to select substring of DateTime in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to get just the AM/PM part from a DateTime column in SSRS. I have tried both `=Right(Fields!Start_Time.Value,2)` and `=Format(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"tt")` and both gives me A3s and P3s. I have also tried `=IIF(DatePart("hour",Fields!Start_Time.Value) < 12, "AM", "PM")` which just displayed the original DateTime, unformatted. What is causing this and how do I just get the AM/PM part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your field is a DATE/TIME or does it just look like a Date/Time field?

The only thing I can think of is that your field isn't actually a date/time type but just looks like one.

Try using CDATE to convert the Start Time field to a Date/Time that can be Formatted.

```
=Format(CDATE(Fields!Start_Time.Value),"tt")
```

UPDATE: 
After reviewing your comments, I think you are putting the formula in the FORMAT property and not in the Expression. The way the question was written, I assumed you were populating the text box's **Expression** with the data formatted using the FORMAT function. If set the text box to the Start Time **field** and want to format using the FORMAT property, you would just put the in the FORMAT (tt) and not use the FORMAT function.

[image]

Comment: @sleaf - what about when you use NOW? `=FORMAT(CDATE(NOW), "tt")` Have you tried from both Visual Studio and the Report Server? If you are using the FORMAT **property** and not the **Expression**, just use `tt`.

Comment: When I use NOW I get A3. I have not tried in Visual Studio, this is for an SSRS report. I don't know anything about data reporting in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry, read the comment before I read your update to the question. Putting tt in the Format property did the trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try: =IIF( Mid(Fields!Start_Time.Value,12,2) < 12 , "AM", "PM")

Comment: Tried it, some values are A3/P3 and the rest are the original, unformatted datetime strings.